# flask-marshmallow: how to mark all fields as optional only when the method is PUT

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, webargs

I am making a flask restful API, what I'm having trouble with is  marshmallow-sqlalchemy, and webargs.

In short here is my sqlalchemy model:

```
class User(Model):
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(120), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(128))
    creation_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

and this is my schema:

```
class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        strict = True
        sqla_session = db.session

user_schema = UserSchema()
```

and an example of my routes using flask-classful and webargs:

```
class UserView(FlaskView):
    trailing_slash = False
    model = User
    schema = user_schema

    @use_kwargs(schema.fields)
    def post(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            entity = self.model()

            for d in kwargs:
                if kwargs[d] is not missing:
                    entity.__setattr__(d, kwargs[d])
    
            db.session.add(entity)
            db.session.commit()
            o = self.schema.dump(entity).data
            return jsonify({'{}'.format(self.model.__table__.name): o})

        except IntegrityError:
            return jsonify({'message': '{} exist in the database. choose another id'
                   .format(self.model.__table__.name)}), 409


    @use_kwargs(schema.fields)
    def put(self, id, **kwargs):
        entity = self.model.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()

        for d in kwargs:
            if kwargs[d] is not missing:
                entity.__setattr__(d, kwargs[d])

        db.session.commit()
        o = self.schema.dump(entity).data
        return jsonify({'{}'.format(self.model.__table__.name): o})

UserView.register(app)
```

**The problem:**
As you can see in my sqlalchemy model, some fields are not nullable, thus my marshmallow schemda marks them as required. My `get`, `index`, `delete` and `post` methods all work perfectly. But I included post for one reason:

when I try to post a new user with no name for example, a 422 http code is raised because `name` field is required, which is something I want and it is done perfectly.

BUT when editing fields with `put` request, I wish EVERYTHING in my schema becomes optional.. right now if I wanted to update a user, I must provide not only the id.. but ALL other information required by default even if I didn't change them at all.

**In short**, how to mark all fields as "optional" when the method is "put"?

***EDIT:*** just like the solution provided by @Mekicha, I made the following changes:

Change the schema to make the required fields in my model accept the value None. like this:

```
class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        ...
    name = fields.Str(missing=None, required=True)
    email = fields.Email(missing=None, required=True)
    ...
```

change my put and post method condition from this:

```
if kwargs[d] is not missing:
```

to this:

```
if kwargs[d] is not missing and kwargs[d] is not None:
```

Comment: Take a look at the doc on [partial loading](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#partial-loading)

Comment: @Mekicha I kinda get how to use partial loading. but how to specify it in my `use_kwargs` so ALL fields are optional? I tried doing **@use_kwargs(partial=True)** and setting partial to a set of fields but it didn't work :(

Comment: please see my answer, if that can help you

Comment: Instantiate the schema with partial=True like `@use_kwargs(UserSchema(partial=True))`

Comment: @andho Is that actually working for you, or is it a "should work"? Like the OP, I have something like `@use_kwargs(user_schema.fields)`, not `@use_kwargs(user_schema)`, and I don't remember why. But changing `user_schema = UserSchema(strict=True)` to `user_schema = UserSchema(strict=True, partial=True)` didn't make any difference.

I'd love to use `partial` rather than specify individual fields here and there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to make the fields optional during `put`, how about setting the `missing` attribute for the fields. From the [doc](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#specify-default-serialization-deserialization-values):

> missing is used for deserialization if the field is not found in the
>   input data

I think a combination of `missing` and `allow_none`(which defaults to `True` when `missing=None`) as pointed out here: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/dev/src/marshmallow/fields.py#L89 should work for you

Answer (score 1):

You could instantiate the schema with `partial=True` to make all fields optional.